# Python program testing state of water gives incorrect answer for celcius

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program is supposed to take two inputs, the degree unit of measurement either F or C and the temperature then print out the state the water is in. No matter what I put in for C except for 1000 I get the answer that it is a liquid, never frozen or gas. Here is my code:

```
print("Do you use Fahrenheit (F) or Celcius? (C)")
degreeUnit = (input("Enter F or C:")).upper()
temp = int(input("What is the temperature of the water?"))
if degreeUnit == "F" and temp <=32: #checking if unit is F and if water is frozen
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and temp >= 212: #water freezes at 32F is gas at 212 is it gas?
    print("The water is a gas")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and temp >=33 or temp <=211:
    print("The water is a liquid.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp <=0: #water freezes at 0C
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp >=100: #water is gas at 100C
    print("The water is a gas.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp >=1 or temp <=99:
    print("The water is a liquid.")
else:
    print("Please try again, something went wrong.")
input()
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I keep reading it over and over and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your grouping of your conditions in your liquid check for F and C

Comment: Group your conditional `or` statements if you want to compare them with an `and` conditional preceding them. Also, your `or` statements are always `True` given that any real number fits the condition of being equal or greater than `33` **or** lower or equal to 211. Same goes for the Celsius `or` conditional, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always get liquid, you should check the condition for liquid. Is it really what you want? (Hint, it isn't). Check the logic of that last elif statement, and you have the same mistake for the 'F' (Freedom unit :-D )

You may also find it helpful to include parens to see your logic:

```
a=False
b=True
c=True
a and b or c
>>>True
a and (b or c)
>>>False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Group the conditions using parentheses.**

Use this:

```
print("Do you use Fahrenheit (F) or Celcius? (C)")
degreeUnit = (input("Enter F or C:")).upper()
temp = int(input("What is the temperature of the water?"))
if degreeUnit == "F" and temp <=32: #checking if unit is F and if water is frozen
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and temp >= 212: #water freezes at 32F is gas at 212 is it gas?
    print("The water is a gas")
elif degreeUnit == "F" and (temp >=33 or temp <=211):
    print("The water is a liquid.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp <=0: #water freezes at 0C
    print("The water is frozen.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and temp >=100: #water is gas at 100C
    print("The water is a gas.")
elif degreeUnit == "C" and (temp >=1 or temp <=99):
    print("The water is a liquid.")
else:
    print("Please try again, something went wrong.")
input()
```

**Output**

```
Do you use Fahrenheit (F) or Celcius? (C)
Enter F or C:'C'
What is the temperature of the water?0
The water is frozen
```